# Pulling Multiple Files via rsync with WDL

Tags: wdl

I'm trying to run a simple task to pull multiple files via rsync with WDL. The task should be quite simple but how to pull the multiple files subsequently is giving me issues. Below is a snippet of my task and how it's being called:

```
task MultiFiles {
  input {
    String wallclock
    String memory
    Int tmpspace_gb
    Int cpu
    Array[String] remote_files #files we want to pull
    Array[File] local_files
    String data_host 
    Boolean? checksum_flag = false

  }
    #Optionality for WDL
    String checksum = if checksum_flag == true then "--checksum" else ""

  output {
    Array[File] output_files = "${local_files}"
  }

  command <<<

    set -e

    #rsync command
    rsync -avP
      --log-file=rsync.log \
      ~{checksum} \
      "~{data_host}":"~{remote_files}" \
      "~{local_files}"

  >>>
  runtime {
    cpu: 4
    memory: "2GB"
  }
}
```

Call

```
    call MultiFiles {
      input:
        #Task Resources
        remote_files=remote_files,
        data_host=data_host,
        local_files=local_files
}
```